# GNU Radio aliases occurrence dependent on data format

Tags: rf, digital-communications, gnuradio

My setup is simply this:

[image]

I'll post some slides I made below which explain my issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why doesn't the 700 Hz alias occur if I use the complex data format, but is shown for float data format? I suspect it has something to do with Euler's formula but can't really see it if so.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you need not bring in the concept of aliasing to this discussion. Note that the 500Hz signal also shows only one peak in the spectrum. Repeat the *setting-to-float* operation for that signal also. Then you will see two peaks in the fft for that signal also, even though aliasing didn't occur. For real valued signal, the magnitude plot of the fft is *symmetric* about zero frequency. The peaks will appear in pairs. For complex valued signals, this need not be so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real sinusoid \$x(t) = \cos{(\omega t + \phi)}\$, when viewed in the frequency domain through a Fourier transform, consists of two complex sinusoids: one at positive frequency, and one at negative frequency:

$$ x(t) = \frac{1}{2} e^{j \omega t + \phi} + \frac{1}{2} e^{-j \omega t + \phi} $$

The imaginary components of these two terms cancel out and the real components add, leaving just the real sinusoid.

On the other hand, a complex signal generator just yields a positive frequency term \$e^{j \omega t + \phi} = \cos{(\omega t + \phi)} + j\sin{(\omega t + \phi)}\$. In the frequency domain, this is one peak.

However, I disagree slightly with the wording on the slides that calls this "aliasing" (or am confused by the presentation they use because of a lack of context). Aliasing, in the definition I use, is frequencies outside \$\left[-\frac{f_s}{2}, -\frac{f_s}{2}\right]\$ appearing in that range.

For example, with a sampling frequency of 2 kHz, a 1700 Hz real sinusoid would have a component at +1700 Hz, which would alias to -300 Hz (i.e. 1700 Hz - fs). At the same time, it has a component at -1700 Hz, which would alias to +300 Hz. Likewise, a 1300 Hz real sinusoid would alias its positive component to +300 Hz and its negative component to -300 Hz -- it would look the same as the 1700 Hz real sine because those components are indistinguishable.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a bunch.